# Setting FlipClock.js digit to zeros after it stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I am trying to set the FlipClock.js digits to zeros after is stops, but can't find a way in the documentation to do it.

I want it to display 00:00:00

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
var datepass = 'August 23, 2018 15:34:30',
 date = new Date(datepass),
 now = new Date(),
 diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000),
 clock = $('#clock1').FlipClock(diff,{
  clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
  countdown: true
 });
clock.start();

var timer1 = setInterval(checktime, 1000);

function checktime() {
 t = clock.getTime();
 if ( t <= 0 ){
  clock.stop();
  clearInterval(timer1);
  
  /* set the digits to zeros by jQuery */
  $('#clock1 ul li a div.up div.inn, #clock1 ul li a div.down div.inn').text(0);
  
  /* hide the first and second digits */
  $('#clock1 ul.flip').eq(0).hide();
  $('#clock1 ul.flip').eq(1).hide();
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flipclock@0.8.2/dist/flipclock.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flipclock@0.8.2/dist/flipclock.min.js" integrity="sha256-BiezSH09N4/rvsbi2M+VY0et7UQYP3VjtbdFHo46N1g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="clock" id="clock1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a `countdown`, then - according to the Options section on their [homepage](http://flipclockjs.com/#)(*) - you're not passing the option correctly, it should be:

```
$('#clock1').FlipClock(diff, {
  clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
  clockFaceOptions: {
    countdown: true
  }
});
```

Then it stops naturally at zero.

However you `diff` is negative, which displays weird stuff and leaves me wondering if I understood what you're trying to do.

(*): which is not reflected on their [faces page](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/hourly-counter).

Comment: I added an old date to ensure that the countdown will be stopped as the date already passed out. Changing the option as you mentioned didn't make any difference. The counter should stop at zero and all digits set to zeros like 00:00:00

Comment: Here is [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27gq4edm/4/), with a 5s countdown that stops at 0. I directly copied your HTML and my solution, just replaced `diff` with `5` and appended a `.start()`

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly now. The problem with the diff is that it was a negative number. A check must be added to set the diff value to 0 if it is less than 0, so the timer will stop correctly without showing weird numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue... And [Amr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125344/amr)'s (OP) comment was my answer:

> The problem with the diff is that it was a negative number. A check must be added to set the diff value to 0 if it is less than 0...

Based on his code, the addition is:

```
var datepass = 'August 23, 2018 15:34:30',
date = new Date(datepass),
now = new Date(),
diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000);

diff = diff < 0 ? 0 : diff;  // <-------- here

var clock = $('#clock1').FlipClock(diff,{
    clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
    countdown: true
});
```

So yes, the timer "naturally" stops at zero when running. But when `diff` is negative on page load, it is an issue... Simple to fix, fortunately.

With this fix, the only (possibly annoying) thing left is that console log message `Trying to start timer when countdown already at 0`.